# Where does Safari save recently closed tabs?

Tags: macos, terminal, safari, memory

When I force the immediate exit of Safari with open tabs, then restart Safari, this message appears:

> Safari was last opened when opening Windows terminated immediately. Do
> you want try to open the windows again to open?
>
> If you stipulate that window won't do it again you may have to open
> and position the window yourself.

I deleted the Safari location before opening Safari, so before the message appeared, everything in `~/Library/Safari` was deleted. How can Safari restore everything? I also used the `purge` command line utility to purge the RAM.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Possibly in `~/Library/Saved Application State/com.apple.Safari.savedState` but I don't want to delete mine to test.

Confirmed as working, by the OP in comments.

Comment: Glad to hear it - I'll update the answer now we have it confirmed. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When you do have `~/Library/Safari` there's a file `LastSession.plist` in it that is exactly what it's name says. I often save sessions that I want to come back to by taking copies of that file & copying them back when I want to revisit a given session.