# MacOS Mojave: Restore closed Safari tabs from earlier than last session?

Tags: safari, mojave, tabs

I’m running Safari 14.1.2 under MacOS 10.14.6 Mojave, and accidentally all my Safari tabs got closed. I only noticed this some days after running the last session, so I cannot “reopen all windows from last session” — the missing tabs are no longer in the last session’s record.

Searching for a way to recover, I found this question, [Where does Safari save recently closed tabs?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/422034/where-does-safari-save-recently-closed-tabs), but alas, neither of the two suggestions there has worked for me. In separate attempts, I did copy over both `~/Library/Safari/LastSession.plist` and `~/Library/Saved Application State/com.apple.Safari.savedState` from backups, but upon relaunching Safari will still not open the windows and tabs I had open before.

Any further suggestions that would work for Safari under Mojave?

Comment: Have you checked in Safari > History > Recently Closed?

Comment: Th u 4 this sugg. I tried now a series of Reopen Last Closed, and that brings back a number of recently closed tabs — but these are all tabs that I closed intentionally, not those that got closed when all my open windows in Safari, with numerous tabs that I had kept open, got closed unintentionally. It is these latter that I want to restore. And those I want go far further back in time than what a series of Reopen Last Closed returns. I can see All History (back to 31 Dec 2020) — but that’s a jumble of both tabs I want to be open and those I can forget :-(

Answer (score 2):

So I tried again: loaded  `~/Library/Safari/LastSession.plist` from Time Machine backup, and then `Reopen All Windows from Last Session`. This time, miraculously, it worked :-) God knows why it failed the first time…

Answer (score 0):

Try Show All History, Recently Closed, or a series of Reopen Last Closed…

[image]

Comment: You're on Mojave?

Comment: @Thinkr - yup, last decent OS they made :P

Comment: @Tetsujin: as I wrote, I cannot “reopen all windows from last session” because the missing tabs are not from the last session, but from an earlier one.

Comment: muwa6 - I made no mention at all of reopen from last session, as that was the one you already said you'd tried.

Comment: @Tetsujin Just to know :D

Comment: @Tetsujin: Sorry, my misreading. — I tried now a series of Reopen Last Closed, and that brings back a number of recently closed tabs — but these are all tabs that I closed intentionally, not those that got closed when all my open windows in Safari, with numerous tabs that I had kept open, got closed unintentionally. It is these latter that I want to restore. And they go far further back in time than what a series of Reopen Last Closed returns. I can see All History (back to 31 Dec 2020) — but that’s a jumble of tabs I want to be open and those I can forget.